# Why TinyMCE add dir="ltr" to all my pasted tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I've a website where I'm using TinyMCE. I don't know why but if I select a text from Google doc file (or any other source) and paste it in my TinyMCE, when I change to "view source" it shows dir="ltr" in every tag. But, if I paste the same text in the editor of the home page of [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com), it doesn't happens.

Any ideas...?

Edit 1: if you want, test this behaviour here: http://freeonlinehtmleditor.com/. Try to select a couple of paragraphs from a GDoc file and paste it there. Then look at the source. After that to the same in http://www.tinymce.com/

Comment: Do you have RTL support enabled in your TinyMCE?

Comment: Unless it come enabled by default, no. I don't have included directionality plugin neither.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Docs support both LTR(Left-to-Right editing) and RTL(Right-to-Left editing).
RTL is for such as Hebrew and Arabic.
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/65166?hl=en

And from Oct. 2013, TinyMCE also started to support RTL.
https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/commit/a60b5328499254e28342614ebedab591137efcbe

When you copy a paragraph from Google Docs to TinyMCE, TinyMCE keeps its LTR/RTL attributes with its `directionality` class.
http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:directionality

---

**EDIT:**

To avoid this, you can add the `paste` plugin like this:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    plugins: ["paste code moxiemanager"]
});
```

To compare it to the "without-paste" version, you can go like this:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    plugins: ["code moxiemanager"] // without 'paste'
});
```

The document of `paste` is here :http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin3x:paste

---

**NOTE:**

When you see the source code of the http://www.tinymce.com/ , TinyMCE is initialized like below. You can find the word `paste` on the line 3 in the `plugins:[  ]` section:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste moxiemanager"
                                                ^^^^^
    ],
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter 
         alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
    autosave_ask_before_unload: false,
    max_height: 200,
    min_height: 160,
    height : 180
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm totally agree with what you said... but I want to find a way to configure TinyMCE to work in the same way as it works in the TinyMCE homepage (I want to paste and don't want to see any dir attribute).

Comment: @dariomac, thanks. Which version of TinyMCE do you use exactly ? In newest version 4.0, it doesn't happen with default init() options.  http://fierce-trucker-56-121435.apne1.nitrousbox.com/tinymce/1.html

Comment: thanks for your answer. However, if you try to copy/paste any text inside GDoc file and paste it in your sample editor and after see the source code, you will see dir attributes.

Comment: @dariomac, I found a solution and edited my answer :)

Comment: this seems to work. However, this not explain why the TinyMCE editor in their homepage works and we have to add the valid_elements entry to make it work. Instead of this I've tested paste_postprocess : function(pl, o) {
  $("*[dir]", $(o.node)).removeAttr("dir");
}

Comment: @dariomac Thanks. I update my answer. You would like to add the `paste` plugin .

Comment: you earned the bounty! Thxs!

Comment: @naota Adding the paste plugin doesn't seem to solve the dir="ltr" issue on pasting from word anymore. Has something changed wrt TinyMCE? I am using TinyMCE v4

Comment: @naota Edit: I am using v3 -> any change here?

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way is to clear the text formatting from `Google Docs` editor, or just copy and paste it into any `txt` editors then to your `TinyMCE`.

Comment: Yes... but that doesn't explain why when I paste the same selection of google doc in the TinyMCE instance of the TinyMCE home page, it works.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't quickly add the paste plugin to my TinyMCE configuration; I'm working in Laravel with the Voyager plugin and TinyMCE is part of the Voyager admin interface, so my environment is probably a little more restrictive than what others have. But, I have the same problem: TinyMCE is cluttering up my HTML with attributes that I don't believe I need and that I don't include in my template files (so my HTML is both messy now and inconsistent).

I removed directionality from TinyMCE's output by restricting what tags TinyMCE is allowed to include. In my voyager_additional.js file (which is hooked up to Voyager in config/voyager.php), I added:

```
function tinymce_setup_callback(editor)
{
    editor.settings.valid_elements = "a[href|target=_blank],strong/b,div[align],br,h2,h3,ul,li";

    // other code...

}
```

and because I don't explicitly allow dir attributes, they are gone. This solution has the added benefit of preventing my editors from including 37 H1 tags or other things I'd prefer they didn't do.